# Javascript to back button

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have one GridView with Employee search results in it.

This GridView shows results of EmpNo, EmpName, Salary. For each EmpNo cell in the GridView, there is a link to ManageEmployee.aspx page.

Till here okay, no problem.

In ManageEmployee.aspx page there are two buttons 1.Update, 2.Cancel

When user clicks on Cancel button, the page should navigate to Employee results page.

Can anybody give suggestion how to do this?

Comment: Are you looking for code that will send the user to previous page via javascript? Is that what you really want?

Comment: Yes Dipen, exactly. Thanks for your quick reply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add in a HyperLink field in a TemplateField. If you pass the search term to the details page as `~/Details.aspx?query=John%20Smith` this will make a URL that is `~/SearchResults.aspx?query=John%20Smith`.

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1" runat="server" NavigateUrl='<%# String.Format("~/SearchResults.aspx?query={0}", Request["query"]) %>'>Cancel</asp:HyperLink>)
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

If you want JavaScript (be careful about postbacks)

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <a href="#" onclick="javascript:window.history.go(-1);">Cancel</a>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

If you have troubles with postbacks you will probably need to add in a direct URL like the HyperLink version above, or simply a window.location=".." version instead of history.go().

Answer (score 0):

if you are looking for navigation using `ASP.Net` you can use

`Response.Redirect("Your URL")`

[Example on how to use it - MSDN](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/307903)

Answer (score 0):

Use the onclick attribute:

```
onclick="javascript:window.location.href='/relative/path/to/employeeResults.aspx'"
```